# Django Views has an issue not allowing all Context Variables to appear in template

Tags: django

I have made a Slider Model which contains 3 images and Texts related to it to slide in a Carousel

My issue is that I want these images to be shown as per the order assigned as per the model but only one appears.

If I remove the `{% if sliders %}`    `{% for slider in sliders %}` the latest image only appears because in the views it is filtered by  `.latest('timestamp')`

I have also tried to replace `.latest('timestamp')` in the views with `.all()` it still didn't work

This is the model:

```
class Slider(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    image = models.ImageField(blank=False, upload_to='Marketing')
    order = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    header_text = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=True, blank=True)
    middle_text = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=True, blank=True)
    footer_text = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=True, blank=True)
    button_text = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=True, blank=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['order']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_image_url(self):
        return "%s/%s" % (settings.MEDIA_URL, self.image)
```

This is the view:

```
class HomeView(ListView):
    model = Item
    paginate_by = 10
    template_name = "home.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(HomeView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        try:
            context['marketing_message'] = MarketingMessage.objects.filter(
                active=True).latest('timestamp')
        except MarketingMessage.DoesNotExist:
            context['marketing_message'] = None
        try:
            context['slider'] = Slider.objects.filter(
                active=True).latest('timestamp')
        except Slider.DoesNotExist:
            context['slider'] = None
        return context
```

This is the template:

```
        {% if slider %}
        {% for slider in sliders %}
            <div class="carousel-item {% if forloop.first %} active {% endif %}">
                <div class="view" style="background-image: url('{{ slider.get_image_url }}'); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover;">
                    <div class="mask rgba-black-strong d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
                        <div class="text-center white-text mx-5 wow fadeIn">
                            <h1 class="mb-4">
                            {% if slider.header_text %}
                                <strong>{{ slider.header_text }}</strong>
                            {% endif %}
                            </h1>
                            <p>
                                {% if slider.middle_text %}
                                <strong>{{ slider.middle_text }}</strong>
                                {% endif %}
                            </p>
                            <p class="mb-4 d-none d-md-block">
                                {% if slider.footer_text %}
                                <strong>{{ slider.footer_text }}
                                </strong>
                                {% endif %}
                            </p>
                            {% if slider.button_text %}                            
                            <a target="_blank" href="" class="btn btn-outline-white btn-lg">
                            {{ slider.button_text }}
                            <i class="fas fa-graduation-cap ml-2"></i>
                            </a>
                            {% endif %}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        {% endfor %} 
        {% endif %}
```

Comment: You don't provide any `sliders` from the view.

Comment: @IvanStarostin it is in the function below the Homeview class

Comment: Your context dict has `slider` key but in template you call it `sliders`. Try changing context key to `sliders`

Comment: @Hisham___Pak. True I have changed `{% if sliders %}` to be  `{% if slider %}` but still not showing

Comment: change it here too man `{% for slider in sliders %}`

Comment: @Hisham___Pak if i changed  `{% for slider in sliders %}` to  `{% for item in slider %}`  I get an Error `Exception Value: 'Slider' object is not iterable`

Comment: In your `view` change `latest` to `order_by`. `latest` always returns the latest instance based on field, here `timestamp`.

Comment: @Jeet i did but still nothing showed up

Comment: I added an answer please consider seeing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make following changes

views.py

```
class HomeView(ListView):
    model = Item
    paginate_by = 10
    template_name = "home.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(HomeView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        try:
            context['marketing_message'] = MarketingMessage.objects.filter(active=True).latest('timestamp')
        except MarketingMessage.DoesNotExist:
            context['marketing_message'] = None
        try:
            context['sliders'] = Slider.objects.filter(active=True).order_by('timestamp')
        except Slider.DoesNotExist:
            context['sliders'] = None
        return context
```

template

```
{% if sliders %}
{% for slider in sliders %}
    #Your html code
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have declared `context['slider']` in `views.py` whereas, you call it `sliders` in your templates.

Now you will not be able to loop through because that calls one object only so do the following changes in `views.py`:

```
context['slider'] = Slider.objects.filter(active=True).latest('timestamp')
```

to

```
context['slider'] = Slider.objects.filter(active=True)
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer the problem is not yet solved as the images still are not shown for some reason I have placed your code and nothing happens the only time the images appears is when I remove   ` {% if slider %}` and `{% for object in sliders %}` while in the views `.latest('timestamp')  ` is there.

Comment: can you `print(context['slider'])` in `views.py` and see in console what is the output after reloading the page?

Comment: <QuerySet [<Slider: Slider 1>, <Slider: Slider 2>, <Slider: beach>]>

Comment: are `{{ slider.header_text }}`, `{{ slider.middle_text }}`, `{{ slider.footer_text }}` being shown, I guess this can be your `background-image: url('{{ slider.get_image_url }}');` error.